# Definition of scalar product in relation to projections

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

So if $x \in X$ is an element in a vector space $X$, then $\forall x \in X$:
$$x = e_ix^i$$ 
where $e_i$ is a basis for $X$. However, I encountered that this is equivalent to:
$$x = e_i (e_i, x)$$
where $(e_i, x)$ is the scalar product between $e_i$ and $x$. Why is the following true? $$x^i =  (e_i, x)$$
My lecturer mentioned something about projections, but I don't understand the relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the basis $e_i$ is orthonormal, that is $(e_i, e_j) = \delta_{ij}$ ($1$ if $i = j$ or $0$ otherwise). You can expand any vector $x$ in this bases

$$
x = x^1 e_1 + x^2 e_2 + \cdots  = x^ie_i
$$

Now multiple both sides by some vector of the basis, say the first one

$$
(e^1, x) = x^1\underbrace{(e_1, e_1)}_{=1} + x^2\underbrace{(e_2, e_1)}_{=0} + x^3\underbrace{(e_3, e_1)}_{=0} + \cdots = x^1
$$

You can repeat the same experiment for all the other components, and quickly realize that

$$
(e^i, x) = x^i
$$

Comment: So does the basis $e_i$ need to be orthonormal?

Comment: @daljit97 Yes, but remember that you can always use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, so it is not such a big thing to assume